# What is the minimum number of people required?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

Let there be $k$ professions and let there be $b$ blocks. We have $n$ people who belong to these $k$ professions, and each person belongs to exactly one profession. We want to place these $n$ people in the $b$ blocks.

For the $j$-th block, let $n_{ij}$ be the number of people belonging to profession $i$ in $j$-th block. Note, some of the $n_{ij}$ may be $0$.

Let $n_j$ be the number of people in $j$-th block. Then $\sum_{i=1}^k n_{ij}=n_j$. Further, $n=\sum_{j=1}^b n_j$. Also assume $n_j>0$ for all $j$.

We want to place the $n$ people in the $b$ blocks (ordering unimportant) such that for every $j,j'$ there exists $i$ such that $n_{ij}>0,n_{ij'}>0$.

If $k,b$ are given, what can be the minimum possible value of $n$?

I would love it if someone can help me get the solution. I believe the answer is $n>b+k-1$ (though unsure about it) but cannot really prove it.

Comment: The lower bound is optimistic I think. Consider $b=k=4$, and model our blocks as a graph. 2 blocks are connected if they share some profession. If we give 2 people of each profession, then each profession can connect at most 2 blocks. But we need  6 connections (edges)! So this cannot be arranged

Comment: In a similar vein: $n = b+k-1$ is not strictly impossible, let $b  = 2$, $k=2$. Then any set of $3 = 2 + 2 - 1$ people will have $2$ of the same occupation, put one in each block and the claim is satisfied. Methinks no linear bound will work generically.